# sidebar is broken when opening modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I have a modal form when I click the button I get the form with student data in it.

so the problem is when the modal is opened the sidebar is broken.

here's a screenshot of my problem :

[Screen shot](http://prntscr.com/j1r2m7)

modal :

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="memberModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
     <div class="modal-dialog">
         <div class="modal-content">
             <div class="modal-header">
                 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title" id="memberModalLabel">Edit Member Detail</h4>
             </div>
             <div class="dash">

             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

I tried to remove `position: relative;` for the modal.

but it's not doing anything

when the sidebar is left to right the modal is not affecting the sidebar but when I change it to right to left it breaks

Any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding :

```
.modal-open[style] {
padding-right: 0px !important;
}
```